# Converting a sentence from passive voice to active voice

Tags: passive-voice, active-voice

I wish to convert a sentence written in the passive voice to that of the active voice. The sentence is in a covering letter for a job. Here it is:

"I am experienced in reviewing, drafting, and amending a broad range of contracts, these include supply of service contracts and supply of goods contracts."

I would be grateful if someone could show me what the above looks like in the active voice.

Kind regards.

Comment: It is already in the active voice.

Comment: 'Be + V-ed' isn't always the passive (John was injured [by the ball]). 'The window was broken' may be passive ('The window was broken by the ball') or may be using the copula + predicative adjective ('The window was broken, and to judge by the mould growing inside the shed, had been for quite some time').

Comment: 1. **I am an** expert in... (A) 2. **I am** experienced in...(A)  3. **I'm** knowledgeable in…(A)  4. **I have** considerable experience in... (A) 5. Reviewing, drafting and amending contracts **are performed by me**. (P) 6. In my last job reviewing, drafting and amending contracts **were done / performed by me** (P)

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. Very helpful. It is something that has bothered me, but I am not as knowledgeable as the people who responded to my request(!), so was unable to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Note that in *"I am experienced in reviewing"*, ***experienced*** is a participle used as an adjective. These are called [participial adjectives](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-a-participial-adjective-1691486). You cannot **be experienced by someone*. So no passive here.
If the participle bothers you that much, you could say:

> I have experience in ...

It seems to be [more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%20am%20experienced%20in%2CI%20have%20experience%20in&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20am%20experienced%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20have%20experience%20in%3B%2Cc0).

***Experienced*** is recorded in dictionaries as an adjective with a *very active* meaning:

> ***having*** skill or knowledge because you ***have done something*** many times:
>
> - an ***experienced*** teacher
> - She is very ***experienced*** in marketing. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/experienced))

Comment: Thank you for your response. It seems the consensus is that my problem sentence is not passive, but active. I did not think there was a problem with what I was saying, but the Microsoft grammar check function and Grammarly were telling me that the subject sentence and ones similar to it were passive and that I may wish to consider making them active, but I could not work out how to.

Comment: Well, grammar checkers are not people. When they detect Subject+Verb BE + word ending in -ED, their red lights" go for _passive contruction_. Can't blame them, they are only computer programmes. So don't trust them completely.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your objective, you might gain a pinch more punch and conciseness by avoiding the construction using *am* to link *experienced.*

*I **am** experienced in reviewing, drafting, and amending a broad range of contracts, **these** include supply of service contracts and supply of goods contracts.*

For example:

*My [adjective?] experience in ... includes ...*

This can also help limit the monotony of beginning many sentences with *I*. Try to ensure each word adds something in addition to working grammatically.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, I want to gain a bit more punch, and I also want to communicate a) what I have experience of, and, b) that I am experienced in it. I will dip into the thesaurus too!